# Titanium device back button not closes my application properly

Tags: android, ajax, mobile, titanium

I am working Android mobile application using Titanium studio.I have developed small application.After logging into application will display two tabs on my new window; after clicking any other tab it opens correct window.But when I click device back button (back button on my android phone simulator) it not closes my application. it render one blank window and if I again click back button it closes my application

after log in successful I used window-name.close(); so that it not render again sign in form. But I am using .close() for only sign in window so that after clicking back it will not show sign in  page again.

```
var user1 = Ti.UI.createWindow
({
        navBarHidden : false,
        url:'main.js',
});user1.open();
w.close();
home.close();
```

========== main=============

```
var mainTabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var feedWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    url:'home/feed.js'
});
var feedTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    title:'Feed',
    window:feedWin
});
var listWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    url:'home/list.js'
});
var listTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    title:'List',
    window:listWin
});

mainTabGroup.addTab(feedTab);
mainTabGroup.addTab(listTab);
mainTabGroup.open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set

```
exitOnClose:true
```

on whichever window you want to trigger the closing of  the app when that window is closed

[From the appcelerator documentation, Titanium.UI.Window](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Window-object)

> (Android only.) Boolean indicates if the application should exit when
>   the Android back button is pressed while the window is being shown.
>   You can only set this as a createWindow({...}) option. Setting it
>   after window creation will no effect.